# Using push notifications service along with WCF for windows store application

Tags: wcf, windows-8, push-notification, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I'd like to build an app based on WCF service and Win8 as presentation layer. I will have messaging capabilities in the app so any user must see updates on the tile (when new messages arrive). As I understand I need to use "*Push notifications service*" mechanism somehow to update all client s tiles with new arrived messages? How would app work? It should call directly to WCF service and then WCF service should call to push notifications service, or firstly Win8 calls to notification service which calls to WCF? Can somebody clarify me how all this stuff can communicate with each other? Perhaps I should think about WCF Duplex approach? Is it possible to make WCF service to be Push notification service as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 
[The Windows Push Notification Services (WNS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh913756.aspx). Your app requests a notification channel. Then it will call the WCF service to send it that channel. The WCF service will send a POST request to the notification channel (which is a URI) in order to notify the app. The data of the request is in XML format (you can read about it in the link).

> The Windows Push Notification Services (WNS) enables third-party
>   developers to send toast, tile, badge, and raw updates from their own
>   cloud service. This provides a mechanism to deliver new updates to
>   your users in a power-efficient and dependable way.
>
> It involves these steps:
>
> ```
> - Your app sends a request for a push notification channel to the Notification
>   Client Platform.
> - The Notification Client Platform asks WNS to create a notification channel.
>   This channel is returned to the calling device in the form of a Uniform
>   Resource Identifier (URI).
> - The notification channel URI is returned by Windows to your app.
> - Your app sends the URI to your own cloud service. This callback mechanism is
>   an interface between your own app and your own service. It is your
>   responsibility to implement this callback with safe and secure web standards.
> - When your cloud service has an update to send, it notifies WNS using the
>   channel URI. This is done by issuing an HTTP POST request, including the 
>   notification payload, over Secure Sockets Layer (SSL). This step requires 
>   authentication.
> - WNS receives the request and routes the notification to the appropriate
>   device.
> ```